# replace word using regex with specific conditions

Tags: python, regex

How would I use the python "re" module to replace a word, i.e., `'co'` with an empty string, i.e., `''` in a given text, only if:

- the word is at the end of the text and there's a space before the word
- the word is not the final word in the text but there's a space at beginning, and then another space at the end of the word

I.e.,

```
# word is not the final word in the text but there's a space at beginning, and then another space at the end of the word
txt = 'A co is mine'
txt_after_replace = 'A is mine'
txt = 'A column is mine'
txt_ater_replace = 'A column is mine'
# word is the end of the text and there's a space before the word
txt = 'my co'
txt_after_replace = 'my'
txt = 'my column'
txt_after_replace = 'my column'
```

If I do: `txt.replace(' co', '')` these two cases will fail: `txt = 'my column', txt_ater_replace = 'A column is mine'`.  Since it won't check for the end of text right after the word or for a space in the text right after the word.

I think the re.sub module would come to the rescue here but I'm unsure how.

This should work for any general word, i.e., `'co'` in this case.

Comment: I don't think you can match both criteria at the same time. A regex for the first would be `\b\w+$` (which would slightly over-match if there's punctuation before the word) and the second one could use capture groups `" (\w+) .*$"`

Comment: @Beefster thanks for the help, it turns out to be possible based on answer I accepted.

Comment: I realized after I said that that you meant "either" of the conditions.

Comment: @Beefster get it, thanks, not clearer Q, I know, apologies for the english... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match both criteria using following regex.

**Regex:** `(?:\sco\s|\sco$)`

**Explanation:**

- `\sco\s` matches `co` preceded and succeed by a space.
- `\sco$` matches `co` at end preceded by a space.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3B1m66/1/)**

In python:

```
import re
str = "coworker in my company are not so co operative. silly co"
res = re.sub(r'(?:\sco\s|\sco$)', ' ', str)
print(res)
```

**Result:** `coworker in my company are not so operative. silly`

<kbd>**[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/WAWQTM)**</kbd>

Comment: or even better `(\s?\bco\b\s?)`

Comment: @sKwa that one seems to fail in this case: re.sub('(\s?\bco\b\s?)', ' ', 'my co sa')

Comment: @sKwa: Optional space will skip even if it's present.

Comment: @Rahul lol "coworker in my company are not so co operative. silly co"

Comment: @Dnaiel, I used in Rahul's feedle and it works in feedle O_o

Comment: @Rahul, yeap, my bad

Answer (score 0):

you can use [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) regex

`\sco(?=$|\s)`

explanation:

- `space` follow by `co`, then assert what follow by `co` must be either
  `space` or `end of text`

python code

```
import re
txt = 'A co is mine, A column is mine, my column, my co'
new_txt = re.sub('\sco(?=$|\s)', '', txt)
# 'A is mine, A column is mine, my column, my'
```